# meaning of "self-parodying"

Tags: meaning-in-context

1. Does ***"self-parodying"*** imply that some of Rockman's artworks are  parodies of his own previous artworks?
2. Does ***"puncture"*** imply that his self-parodying works lack the romance found in his previous works?

> Context:
>
> Rockman bring a whiff of Romanticism to science, presumably derived
>   from his childhood pottering round museum displays with his mother at
>   a comforting distance, but in his provocative ***self-parodying*** works he
>   ***punctures*** this romance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. He apparently does that on purpose to create an effect (here, to be provocative).
2. Also yes. "Puncture" evoke the idea of a punctured balloon that is "deflated," thus less voluminous. The implication is that romance would go against his goals in his provocative works, so he removes it on purpose.